# Microtype package is not supported dvips output

Tags: microtype, dvi, postscript, font-expansion

I am using `microtype` package for good kerning text output.

I am using below mentioned settings in my tex file.

```
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{size=normalsize-}%disable Ligatures
```

I compile below commands and i get the PDF output for TeX compilation.

```
pdflatex sam.tex
```

I am getting the good kerning PDF output below mentioned.

[image]

The same set up i am using the `dvi-ps-pdf` method. But the microtype package kerning is not working for me. I am using the below commands.

```
latex filename.tex
dvips -t unknown filename.dvi
ps2pdf filename.ps
```

[image]

See the both image output. The kerning space is totally changed `pdflatex` output and `dvips-ps-pdf` output.

I need a same kind of output both `pdflatex` and `dvips-ps-pd`f output.

Please advice how to get the same output for both compailation.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures[f]{size=normalsize-}%disable Ligatures

\begin{document}

\noindent Identifying the decisive matches in international football tournaments is of great relevance for a variety of decision makers such as organizers, team coaches and/or media managers. This paper addresses this issue by analyzing the role of the statistical approach used to estimate the outcome of the game on the identification of decisive matches on international tournaments for national football teams. We extend the measure of decisiveness proposed by Geenens (2014) in order to allow us to predict or evaluate the decisive matches before, during and after a particular game on the tournament. Using information from the 2014 FIFA World Cup, our results suggest that Poisson and kernel regressions significantly outperform the forecasts of ordered probit models. Moreover, we find that although the identification of the most decisive matches is independent of the model considered, the identification of other key matches is model dependent. We also apply this methodology to identify the favorite teams and to predict the most decisive matches in 2015 Copa America before the start of the competition. Furthermore, we compare our forecast approach with respect to the original measure during the knockout stage.

\end{document}
```

Comment: From the user guide of the `microtype` package: "When generating DVI files, font expansion has to be enabled explicitly. Neither letterspacing nor automatic font expansion will work because the postprocessing drivers (dvips, dvipdfm, etc.) resp. the DVI viewer are not able to generate the fonts on the fly." And also: "pdfTeX can create DVI output, too. However, both the DVI viewer and dvips need to find actual fonts. Therefore, expansion will only work if the fonts for different degrees of expansion are readily available." In short, don't be surprised if `microtype` and dvi output don't mix.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was solved by an answer in a comment.

Comment: @MartinSchröder AFAIK, solving a question by a comment is not a reason for closing as off-topic.

Comment: Agreeing with @HeikoOberdiek, I vote to reopen (I would have something new to add were I be able to answer).

Comment: Note that it has nothing to do with kerning. It font expansion, as @Mico implied, which is changing the output. If you need the same output, disable font expansion.

Comment: @cfr - Thanks for making explicit that the OP's issue with dvi output mode and microtype was related to font expansion, not kerning. I had left this point unstated (a bit too implicit, maybe?!) in the comments in which I provided excerpts from the package's user guide.

Answer (score 7):

Automatic font expansion does not work with `pdflatex` in DVI mode (which is what is implicitly called when you run `latex`), therefore `microtype` will switch off font expansion by default. This results in the differences in output you observe. Traditionally, you would have to create and install expanded font instances in advance, which is not something I would recommend to anybody who isn't well-versed in `fontinst` (and inclined to some degree of masochism).

**EDIT**

Unfortunately, and contrary to what I thought earlier, using `dvilualatex` instead of `latex` is not a viable option either. Even though compilation succeeds through the dvips->pstopdf route, the glyphs are not actually transformed (stretched or shrunk), but they are only placed as if they were ([like this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531413/7674)).

Comment: According to the compatibility chart in the `microtype` documentation, LuaTeX only supports automatic font expansion in PDF mode, just like pdfTeX.

Comment: @cfr I know; it's been only recently that I found out. (the chart will be fixed next time round)